# Updating a view based on a dropdownlist in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a dropdownlist which gets the data from a ViewBag. In the view, it's set like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateVoteType", "AlterVote", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "prefsForm", name = "prefsForm" }))  
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>New voting preference</h4>
    <hr />

    <p>Please select the type of vote you wish to change to @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedType, ViewBag.myList as SelectList, "Voting type", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "SelectedIndexChanged()"})</p>
```

My selectedindexchanged script has a single line in it

```
document.prefsForm.submit();
```

What I'm trying to do is when I change the option in the dropdown, it scuttles back to the controller (this isn't working - the selectedindexchanged isn't being hit - if I add `alert.Show("hello!");` to the function, it never shows), does creates a `ViewBag.alertMessage (string)` and a `ViewBag.AlertShow (bool)` which is then propagated into the view.

My controller for handling the change looks like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AlterVote(Dropdown dropType)
    {
        ChangeBoilerPlate(dropType.SelectedType);
        return PartialView(dropType);
    }
```

(ChangeBoilerPlate sets the AlertShow and the alertMessage)

Any ideas where this is going wrong?

Comment: Check the console in the browser to see if it has an error on the script. It may be that the script isn't loaded on the page.

Comment: I changed the BeginForm to just have the method and controller view in and used this.form.submit() for the onchanged which seem to work. Next issue is getting the view to show something when ViewBag.AlertShow is true.

Comment: That would just be
`@if((bool)ViewBag.AlertShow){`
` CONTENT `
`}` If you're trying to access the ViewBag in js, you'll have to assign it to a hidden field then retrieve the value I believe. But don't quote me on it lol